# Find the number of ways that after 20 jumps it returns back to the origin if it is known that it never sat on -1.

Tags: combinatorics

A frog, at the beginning, sits at the origin of the real axis jumps either to left or right by one
unit.

A-)Find the number of ways that after 20 jumps it returns back to the origin
B-)Find the number of ways that after 20 jumps it returns back to the origin if it is known that
it never sat on -1.

Answer: I was thinking that for part A frog must jump 10 times left and 10 times right say -1 for the left side and say +1 for the right side so 10 times -1 10 times +1 then the answer is cmb(20,10) but I couldnt solve part B. I just think that he can not start with -1, or it can not make -1 two times and +1 one times at the first three steps. Maybe we have to do inclusion exclusion but I couldnt go forward thanks for any help

Comment: B is a question about *Dyck paths*.

Comment: Okay I am researching thanks